# Using getElementsByClassname with multiple elements

Tags: vba, import-from-excel, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to retrieve a price from a website using VBA macros.
In general the following code works fine(example):

```
price = html.getElementsByClassName("fpStriked fpStrikedBefore jsStriked").Item(0).innerText
```

However, when the HTML has more than one attribute within the class containing the price, the previous code is unable to retrieve the information.
Here is an example of class containing multiple attributes

```
"span class="fpPrice price jsMainPrice jsProductPrice hideFromPro" itemprop="price" content="33.99" 33<sup>€99</sup>"
```

price = html.getElementsByClassName("fpPrice price jsMainPrice jsProductPrice hideFromPro").Item(0).innerText

How can I adapt the code to get the price (33.99) in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all elements with classes with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (check examples) like `document.querySelectorAll(".fpStriked, .fpStrikedBefore, .jsStriked")`

With `getElementsByClassName` - you can't

**UPD: How to get content from querySelectorAll**

querySelectorAll return HTML Collection, you can use .forEach to get content for each element

```js
let allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".jsProductPrice, .fpStriked, .fpStrikedBefore, .jsStriked")

allItems.forEach(e=>{
  console.log(e.textContent)
})
```

```html
<span class="fpPrice price jsMainPrice jsProductPrice hideFromPro" itemprop="price" content="33.99"> 33<sup>€99</sup></span>
<span class="fpPrice price jsMainPrice jsProductPrice hideFromPro" itemprop="price" content="35"> 35<sup>€00</sup></span>
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually the first code works well. However when I want to retrieve the price from the HTML code below in my question by  price = html.getElementsByClassName("fpPrice price jsMainPrice jsProductPrice hideFromPro").Item(0).innerText it does not work. When using document.querySelectorAll I get a message error "Object required"

Comment: @DavidMorales check update, querySelectorAll return HTML Collection

Answer (score 0):

In the code above getElementsByClassName would select all elements with all 3 of ("fpStriked fpStrikedBefore jsStriked") classes but your span has none of these classes to choose.

Comment: First was only an example of what was working for me in other websites. If I apply the same logic in the second case it does not work price = html.getElementsByClassName("fpPrice price jsMainPrice jsProductPrice hideFromPro").Item(0).innerText